# How to install module pybluez in python for windows 10

Tags: python, module, bluetooth, kivy, pybluez

I can't install module pybluez. When I write to the console: `python -m pip install pybluez`, I get errors:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: It tells you right there

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in module dependencies. Pybluez requires Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 to install, you can install all required tools by the following package:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

After installing the package, reboot your system.

Also, you can install this package:

https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6776-visual-c-redistributable-package.html

Comment: Before installing Pybluez, install the following package, after that, install Pybluez:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/